# XML encoding: inject XML into output

Tags: xml, go

I have a string with an XML fragment and I'd like to inject it into the encoding stream:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    myxml := `<mytag>foo</mytag>`
    enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    root := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "root"}}
    enc.EncodeToken(root)
    enc.EncodeToken(xml.CharData(myxml))
    enc.EncodeToken(root.End())
    enc.Flush()
}
```

I get `<root>&lt;mytag&gt;foo&lt;/mytag&gt;</root>` but I'd like to have `<root><mytag>foo</mytag></root>`

Is there any way I can do this using `enc.EncodeToken()` or something similiar?

Comment: Whats wrong with writing to the Writer directly, i.e. bypassing the encoder: `os.Stdout.Write([]byte(myxml))` ?

Comment: That's what I would do as well — only make sure to `Flush` the encoder before writing directly to the underlying writer.

Comment: I didn't think of the obvious solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to insert raw XML is to write it directly to the stream, os.Stdout in this case.

```
myxml := `<mytag>foo</mytag>`
enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
root := xml.StartElement{Name: xml.Name{Local: "root"}}
enc.EncodeToken(root)
enc.Flush()
os.Stdout.WriteString(myxml)
enc.EncodeToken(root.End())
enc.Flush()
```

This is essentialy what happens if you use the `innerxml` struct tag, but that can only be done through a struct, and would give you one more set of tags representing the struct around your raw xml.

Comment: It doesn't look the »One True Way (TM)«, but it works fine and it solves my problem. Thanks!